# ES6 testing redux saga private functions

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, redux-saga

I have a react native application and want to test my redux saga without exporting the private functions, here is my code.

```
// my saga file (login.js)
function* login(action) {
  try {

  } catch (error) {

  }
}

export default function* loginWatcher() {
  yield takeLatest('SOME_ACTION_TYPE', login);
}

// my test file (login.test.js)
describe('Login Saga', () => {
    describe('watch', () => {
        it('waits for the action', () => {
            const iterator = loginSaga();

            const expectedYield = takeLatest('SOME_ACTION_TYPE', login)
            const actualYield = iterator.next().value;

            expect(expectedYield).to.deep.equal(actualYield);
        });
    });
});
```

I don't want to export the login function in the saga file.
I've read about rewire, but it seems that it doesn't support ES6 yet.

Is there anyway I could do this?

**Update**

I added this code to my saga file so I can use the private functions in the tests

```
let tests = {
  _login: null
}

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  tests._login = login;
};

export { tests };
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, because I hate changing my files so the tests can pass, but it works.

Hope there is another way

Comment: Is there a special reason as to why you don't want to export the login function in the saga file?

Comment: There is no reason to export it, it should only be triggered when the watcher function takes the action.

Comment: Well, one reason to export it is that you can test it.

Comment: you shouldn't export a private function just for your tests, it's not a good practice. my updated code works fine though. have no idea if there is another way.